# “Type 'Values' has no subscript members” error in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database, tableview, swift3

I'm getting error while trying to display an image in tableview.
It is displaying text successfully but it is not showing any images.

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
    var refHandle: UInt!
    var valueList = [Values]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        fetchFirebaseData()
    }

    func fetchFirebaseData() {
        refHandle = ref.child("SwiftJson").observe(.childAdded, with:
            {(snapshot) in
                if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                    print(dictionary)

                    let value = Values() as AnyObject

                    value.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
                    self.valueList.append(value as! Values)

                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
        })
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return valueList.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FTableViewCell
        let value = valueList[indexPath.row]

        cell.fTitle.text = value.title
        let imageUrlString = valueList[indexPath.row]["image"] as! String
        let imageURL = NSURL(string: imageUrlString)
        let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: imageURL as! URL)
        cell.fImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData as! Data)

        return cell
    }
}
```

Here I'm parsing data from Firebase database and trying to show it on tableview.

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: This has been asked and answered soooo many times before!

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problem that you are having is basically that you are trying to access a subscript of a anyObject type. On swift, a anyObject doesn't has subscripts. I don't know why you are casting `Values() as AnyObject`, but thats is probably why you are getting this error.

Also, try to take a look better on the other questions. Your question was probably asked before.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
var valueList = [Values]()
```

Then later:

```
let imageUrlString = valueList[indexPath.row]["image"] as! String
```

Your error message tells you exactly what is wrong:

> “Type 'Values' has no subscript members”

`valueList[indexPath.row]` is of type `Value` which as far as I can guess, does not have a subscript defined in its class.  Which is exactly what the error says.  And you're trying to call a subscript on it:

```
valueList[indexPath.row]["image"]
```

Looking at your earlier code of when you assign `Value`'s to the array, I'm guessing it would unwrap as `[String : AnyObject]`

So you need to:

```
if let value = valueList[indexPath.row] as? [String : AnyObject], let imageUrlString = value["image"] as? String {
    let imageURL = NSURL(string: imageUrlString)
    //etc, etc...
}
```